# Trying to create a power shell script that removes text in a filename between two brackets using regex

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, filenames

I am trying to write a script to take a file name and remove any pair of brackets and the text between them from the string

```
get-childItem *.* -recurse | 
foreach-object {$_ -replace '\(([^\)]+)\)', ''}
```

this will output a list of new values for every file in the folder to the prompt as it should look, however what I can't seem to find is a way to set the new values as the filenames, the plan is to do this for multiple files in a folder with the format "name(Randomnumbers).ext"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not using this recursively ? 
\-[^-]+-\

Comment: Does your use case have any occurences where there are nested parens, i.e.  name(something(nested))?

Comment: @Cobster no there shouldn't be, sorry for late replies I have been away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you want to rename each with the names contained within the parenthesis.  To accomplish that, you can use the $Matches variable that is written by the -match operator.  I'm also assuming you want to maintain the file extension.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '(?<name>.*)(?:\([^\)]+\))(?<ext>.*)') {
        Rename-Item $_ "$($matches['name'])$($matches['ext'])"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just tested this and it does rename the document however i wanted to get rid of the brackets and their contents, this seems to do the opposite just leaving what was inside the brackets, sorry if I wasn't very clear at first

Comment: No problem in that case we can just create a few new capture groups and then recombine them in a similar manner.  Code has been editted.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm, just added the '-LiteralPath' switch to rename-item.